# PHP - How to enable clients to access a web based cloud hosted SaaS service with their active directory credentials?

Tags: php, active-directory, single-sign-on, code-injection

I am looking for a solution to authenticate clients (multiple organization) based on their active directories credentials? If any answer for the process to go  through especially for PHP or Codeigniter would be a great help

Comment: You could use [LDAP](https://www.php.net/ldap) or SAML (ADFS).. The latter being much more difficult

Comment: We use our specific permission, modules and roles. I am not too familiar with active directory, I used LDAP testing but how to link/connect those permissions? Note:The SaaS service includes services which the client agency will be charged

Comment: I've only used LDAP as an SSO-only solution. Getting permissions may prove to be difficult/never 100%. It's the SaaS who should be enforcing permissions (perhaps based on user type), not LDAP imho